# Using Radio buttons in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I receive the following error when I try to use Radio buttons in ionic2

```
Error: Error at 
            /Users/xyz/something/.tmp/pages/new-group/new-group-frequency.ngfactory.ts:528:29 
[16:10:25]  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. 
[16:10:25]  ngc failed 
[16:10:25]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
```

My template looks like below:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <form (submit)="onSubmit($event)" [formGroup]="myForm">

    <ion-list radio-group formControlName="langs">

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Go</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="golang" checked="true"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
  </form>

</ion-content>
```

The associated typescript file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'new-group-frequency',
    templateUrl: 'new-group-frequency.html'
})
export class NewGroupFrequency {
    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(public _nav:NavController) {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            "langs": new FormControl('')
        });

    }

    onSubmit() {}

}
```

Can't figure out what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that when you call the `(submit)="onSubmit($event)"` you're sending a parameter, but in the method's declaration `onSubmit() {}` you're not declaring the event parameter.